# Unable to Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

I am new to visual studio 2012.I'm trying to install Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR package via Package Manager Console.

```
 PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

but its showing error.

```
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package],invalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Can any one know how to solve this problem?